# Need to open file I log to but get file locked exception

Tags: c#, log4net

hI,

I'm using LOG4NET to log to a txt file. However, one of my forms needs to open the txt file (using streamreader) to read the contents and display them in a .txt file. However, I keep getting an exception stating that the file is locked by another process.

Is there a way around this in LOG4NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be help you.

http://www.ericbt.com/Blog/48

Comment: See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.LockingModel.html  property, set it to  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" /> in web.config

Answer (score 3):

If you open the log file with ReadWrite sharing enabled (FileShare.ReadWrite) it will probably work.

You can always uses Process Monitor from http://www.sysinternals.com to see what is happening.

Comment: You can't always use Process Monitor. On Microsoft Azure Websites, you don't have RDP access available. :(